# Native method jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park ANDROID 12

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

Getting this issue in firebase crashalytics only for android 12,

[jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPvEp.png)

This is logs :

```
main (timed waiting):tid=1 systid=17547 
       at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native method)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1079)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1369)
       at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:278)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.Utils.awaitEvenIfOnMainThread(Utils.java:126)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController.handleUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:232)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsController$1.onUncaughtException(CrashlyticsController.java:154)
       at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:55)
       at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1073)
       at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
       at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:2306)
```

I m using crashalytics and getting this at crashalytics and i expect no crashes like this or ANR.

Comment: This looks related to this issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/4345

Comment: this error is coming in chinese devices

Answer (score 0):

which version you are using for firebase crashalytics?

Comment: On production its implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:18.2.9'

Comment: On local now i have added implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx:18.3.3'  will push this but when im confirm this will solve issue i have another issues too same like crashalic ANR  CountDownLatch.await

Comment: @SaurabhJadhav this resolves your problem? I'm facing the same issue here.

Comment: No this doesnt solved my problem and after 1 month due to admob my got deleted from  playstore.

Comment: I also encountered such an error. I think there is such an ANR when there is a location-related operation in the background in my own project but I am not sure.